# Declare a string for IN clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL Server 2008. Is there a way to declare a string with values that I am going to use for an IN in the where statement.

Say I have this working query below, which will result the records for colname = a, b, or c.

```
Select * 
from Table1 
where colname IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

What I want to do is declare this column values in variable and use it inside the IN clause.

```
Declare @StrCols varchar(MAX)
SET @StrCols = 'a', 'b', 'c'  --- Of course, this is not working.

-- Then the query would be:
Select * from Table1 where colname IN (@StrCols)
```

Any suggestion?  Thanks!

Comment: You will have to either use dynamic SQL or one of numerous "split string" functions that produce a table out of the string

Comment: @jpw, not really duplicate because these values needs apostrophy (') wrap around the value, not the IDs where you can do like "1,2,3,4"

Comment: @Milacay My bad then. It did look similar enough to me.

Comment: Dis you try to declare a TABLE of VARCHAR containing all values? The IN clause will then use these elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alas, not easily.  You can one of the following.

If you don't care about performance, you can use

```
where ','+@strvals+',' like '%,' + colname + ',%'
```

If you want to make the SQL more complicated, you can do something like:

```
with strvals as (
      select 'a' as val union al select 'b' union all select 'c'
     )
. . .
where colname in (select val from strvals)
```

You can use dynamic SQL to put the values into the string:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'select . . . where colname in (' + @strvals + ')';

exec sp_executesql @sql;
```

You can do something fancy with a recursive CTE to split string function (which, alas, is not built in).  The split string looks something like:

```
select . . . 
from . . . t cross apply
     dbo.splitstring('a,b,c', ',') ss
where t.colname = ss.value
```

You can look up code for a appropriate split string function if you are interested in this approach.

Answer (score 2):

Try it with dynamic SQL and/or put it in a procedure

Example:

```
Set @query ='SELECT * FROM [A] WHERE colname IN ('+@StrCols+')'

EXEC dbo.proc1 @query
```